# Problem with panel

Tags: asp.net, controls, panel

I cant reach the panelID from the code behind cs file..

```
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" ondatabinding="Panel1_DataBinding" 
        Visible="False">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </asp:Panel>


    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class PanelControl : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Panel1.  --- intellisense doesnt work and there is a red line underneath it!!
    }

    protected void Panel1_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}


    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Forum.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PanelControl.aspx.cs" Inherits="PanelControl" %>

<script runat="server">

    protected void ButtonPanel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
</script>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <p>
        <br />
    </p>
    <p>
    </p>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </asp:Panel>
     <asp:Button ID="ButtonPanel1" runat="server" Text="Panel 1" 
        onclick="ButtonPanel1_Click" />
    <p>
    </p>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Button ID="ButtonPanel2" runat="server" Text="Panel 2" />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Have you done a clean and rebuild?

Comment: yup..still doesnt appear

Comment: may be your panel is inside a template container?  Please post the whole aspx markup of the form

Comment: Yeah, it is inside contentplaceholder.. It has  a masterpage\

Comment: WebSite or WebApplication? Show us Page directive, inherits etc.

Comment: website  dfasdfa,, updated above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as razlebe indicated, you may just have to rebuild.

About once a day, my code will show that a bunch of code is invalid and just doing a rebuild fixes it.

If that does not work, your example shows that you are using a "partial class" and check the designer.cs class to make sure that your variable for the panel is defined.

for example:

```
    public partial class PanelControl {
       protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel Panel1;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to delete designer.cs file then click right button on the aspx file and choose 'Convert to Web Application' item from context menu.

Comment: There is no such option convert to web application